How to install psycopy2 on python3.9?
I try to install psycopy2 on python3.9 via follow instruction
pip install psycopg2

and I got error massages like below:
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

My os is windows 11 profression, how to solve this problem?

Read the error message: If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

The Error Clearly states that pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source. You have to add the directory containing the pg_config executable to your $PATH or install psycopg2-binary to avoid building from source using this command:
pip install psycopg2-binary


So I must install postgresql on my system before I install psycopy2? I just need a client!

No you don't, read the docs  psycopg2 INSTALLATION: pip install psycopg2-binary This will install a pre-compiled binary version of the module which does not require the build or runtime prerequisites described below.

I think I was not clear about the binary package in my answer. But yes, if you just needed a client, psycopg2-binary will suffice.
